# Dividir elementos de uma lista por um número

Tags: python

Olá!

Eu sou estudante de astrofísica e estou precisando saber como se faz para "normalizar" uma função do astropy:

`blackbody_lambda(wavelenght, temperatureG)`

Para este valor específico:

`1279894.374188775erg / (Angstrom cm2 s sr)`.

Utilizo o python.

Abraços!

Comment: O que seria normalizar a função neste caso? Qual é o resultado esperado?

Answer (score 1):

**Divisão**

Você pode fazer:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
myInt = 10
newList = [float(i) / myInt for i in myList]
```

Ou se você precisar manter a referência na lista original

```
myList[:] = [float(i) / myInt for i in myList]
```

Você também pode usar a biblioteca `NumPy`

```
import numpy as np
myArray = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
myInt = 10
newArray = myArray/myInt
```

**Normalização**

Agora se você deseja normalizar em relação à unidade usando a soma:

```
mySum = sum(myArray)
norm = [float(i)/mySum for i in myArray]
```

ou usando o máximo:

```
myMax = max(myArray)
norm = [float(i)/myMax for i in myArray]
```